# How to fit two button within a row ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I was wondering if someone can help me with my row of buttons. They both work outside of the row but not within it. I have attached the code below please let me know if you can help or need more information.

```
 Expanded(
              child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                )
                      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.add),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => StudyPage(
                                title: 'Add a study',
                                selected: 0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
        ],
            )
          ],
            ),
```

Comment: What i would suggest is to avoid using FloatingActionButton() inside the scaffold body since you can add it on scaffold floatingActionButton property. You can follow the answer below but try to utilize the Row properties (mainAxisAlignment & crossAxisAlignment) instead of Expanded Widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I little modified your (Row) code as follows and now it works.

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[

    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),

        FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () async {
             Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) => StudyPage(
                   title: 'Add a study',
                   selected: 0,
                 ),
               ),
             );
          },
        ),


  ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can try this

```
Row(children:[
    Expanded(
      child:
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                )),
     Expanded(
      child:
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                )),
     
    ]);
```

*if it solve your problem, kindly accept it as an answer so that others will get help*

Answer (score 0):

First. `Expanded` only work when place inside `Colum/Row` **children**.

- `Expanded` will take all space of parent `Colum/Row` and expand `Colum/Row` size it possible.
- If you want `Colum/Row` to max size, try add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` to `Colum/Row` instead.

Second. Your code look like has error when `floatingActionButton` not is a Widget when you place in `Colum/Row` children, it is a props of `Scaffold`. Try to replace it by a valid button like `IconButton/ElevatedButton/etc...`. Your `IconButton` missing `onPressed` too.

**Example**:

```dart
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Expanded( // Place `Expanded` inside `Row`
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('First button'),
                    onPressed: () {}, // Every button need a callback
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded( // Place 2 `Expanded` mean: they try to get maximum size and they will have same size
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Second button'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

[image]